# How to write constructors for nested template numeric type classes in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, type-conversion

I'm implementing something where I'd like to "nest" number types. I'm struggling to write constructors in a way that the right-hand side can be a numeric literal. Here's a minified version of my issue:

```cpp
template <typename Scalar>
class A
{
  public:
    A(Scalar a):v(a){};
    Scalar v;
};

template <typename Scalar>
class B
{
  public:
    B(Scalar a):v(a){};
    Scalar v;
};

int main()
{
  A<double> a = 1.0;
  B<double> b = 1.0;
  B<A<double>> ba = 1.0;
}
```

The compiler error is

```
error: no viable conversion from 'double' to 'B<A<double>>'
```

I *don't* want to write `B<A<double>> b = A<double>(1.0);`. Is there a way to change my `A` and `B` classes so the original code works?

Comment: Not sure what the standard says, but on MSVC this code compiles and runs properly. I guess the 1.0 is first converted into a A<double> and then ba is initialized with it. Which compiler are you using ?

Comment: lucky! I'm using Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3) with `-std=c++11`

Comment: gcc-11 (Homebrew GCC 11.2.0_3) 11.2.0 gives a similar error

Comment: @wohlstad Pretty sure MSVS is being "helpful" here.  Both clang and gcc reject as they should since this is doing 2 user provided conversions and you are only ever allowed up to one of those in an implicit conversion sequence.  example: https://godbolt.org/z/f4aWTa5be

Answer (score 5):

What you want is a forwarding constructor.  That is a constructor that takes the arguments to construct the wrapped object and calls that objects constructor with the supplied parameters.  That would look like

```
template <typename Scalar>
class A
{
public:
    A(Scalar a):v(a){};
    Scalar v;
};

template <typename Scalar>
class B
{
public:
    B(Scalar a): v(a) {}
    template <typename... Args, 
              std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible_v<Scalar, Args...>, bool> = true>
    B(Args&&... args) : v(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}
    Scalar v;
};

int main()
{
    A<double> a = 1.0;
    B<double> b = 1.0;
    B<A<double>> ba = 1.0;
}
```

The `std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible_v<Scalar, Args...>, bool> = true` part of the template leverages [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) to constrain this constructor to only work when it would be able to construct a `Scalar`.  This is needed because variadic templates are greedy and will match almost anything, including being considered a better constructor then the copy constructor when provided with a non-const lvalue of the class type.

Comment: holy smokes. Not in a million years would I have figured that out. This seems to work!

Comment: @AlecJacobson Its a bit to take in at first, but you'll soon see all the fun things you can do with these types of techniques.  C++20 makes this easier using concepts which have a more natural syntax but I'm still learning those so went with this approach.

Comment: Whats the advantage of using variadic approach as opposed to normal template? `template <typename Arg>    
    B(Arg arg) : v(std::forward<Arg>(arg)) {}`

Comment: @user16038533 Just making it more generic.

Answer (score 1):

**@NathanOliver** mentioned using concepts and constraints with C++20 in the comment of his answer, so here's how you can do it with C++20 constraint:

```cpp
template <typename Scalar>
struct B
{
public:
    template <typename ... Args>
    requires std::constructible_from<Scalar, Args...>
    B(Args ... args) : v(std::forward<Args>(args) ...) {}
    Scalar v;
};
```

Attempting to construct a `B<A<double>>` from something that cannot convert to `double` will create a compiler error:

```cpp
B<A<double>> ba = "ok"; // Compiler error
// candidate template ignored: constraints not satisfied [with Args = <const char *>]
// because 'std::constructible_from<A<double>, const char *>' evaluated to false
```

---

Note, this doesn't really have an equivalent form that can be written as a concept directly:

```cpp
template<std::constructible_from<Scalar> ... Args>
```

Would be the equivalent of, which is wrong in multiple ways:

```cpp
template<typename Args_1, typename Args_2>
requires std::constructible_from<Args_1, Scalar> && std::constructible_from<Args_2, Scalar>
```

---

However, if you know you will only need constructor with a single parameter, then you can potentially use `std::convertible_to`:

```cpp
template <typename Scalar>
struct B
{
public:
    template <std::convertible_to<Scalar> Arg>
    B(Arg arg) : v(std::forward<Arg>(arg)) {}
    Scalar v;
};
```

This do require an implicit conversion from `Arg` to `Scalar` however, so either the constructor of `Scalar`, or a conversion function from `Arg` to `Scalar` must not be explicit.

---

Side note, the base constructor `B(Scalar a): v(a) {}` at this point is basically redundant, as it will be covered by the templated constructor.